# How to have a maven project refer the package in local repository

Tags: java, maven

I am quite new to maven projects, so sorry if my question is too junior.

I have downloaded 2 java projects, A and B, on my Ubuntu, and try have them packaged from scratch, by using this command-line "mvn compile package install".

For project A, I don't have any issue to do so, and I have seen such in my local repository, after the execution:

```
tree ~/.m2/repository/org/entera/entera-demo-design-1-00/
/home/<user>/.m2/repository/org/entera/entera-demo-design-1-00/
├── 1.0-SNAPSHOT
│   ├── entera-demo-design-1-00-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
│   ├── entera-demo-design-1-00-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
│   ├── maven-metadata-local.xml
│   └── _remote.repositories
└── maven-metadata-local.xml
```

Now, when I was to do the same on project B, it fails with the message as:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project entera-demo-design-1-01: Could not resolve
 dependencies for project org.entera:entera-demo-design-1-01:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: 
Failed to collect dependencies at org.entera:itstack-demo-design-1-00:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: 
Failed to read artifact descriptor for 
     org.entera:entera-demo-design-1-00:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: 
Could not find artifact org.entera:entera-demo-design:pom:1.0-SNAPSHOT -> [Help 1]
```

here is the contents of pom.xml on project B.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>entera-demo-design</artifactId>
        <groupId>org.entera</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>entera-demo-design-1-01</artifactId>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.entera</groupId>
            <artifactId>entera-demo-design-1-00</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

My question is , how to have the project B to refer to the project A jar file which is under .m2 dir.

Thanks,

Jack

here is the contents of parent pom file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>


    <groupId>org.entera</groupId>
    <artifactId>entera-demo-design</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.compilerVersion>1.8</maven.compiler.compilerVersion>
    </properties>

    <modules>
        <module>entera-demo-design-1-01</module>
        <module>entera-demo-design-1-00</module>
    </modules>

    <dependencies>
       .... 
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Comment: The problem is resolving the parent POM. Have you installed that?

Comment: I do have the parent pom file, and I have just  had it attached at the end of my question. What should I do then ?

Comment: According to your error, it's looking for org.entera:entera-demo-design, but your don't have that, you have org.entera:entera-demo-design-1-00.  Change your parent to match.  Also, consider dropping those "-1-00", they look a lot like versions and are only adding to the confusion.

Comment: org.entera:entera-demo-design is the parent POM. I agree that the similarly named artifact IDs probably cause confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [multi-module Maven project](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-modules.html). These should be built from the directory containing the parent POM. When you do so, dependencies between modules will be resolved internally to the build process in what is known as the "reactor".

Change to the directory containing the parent POM, and run this command from that directory: `mvn install`.

This will recursively compile, package, and install *all* of the modules within the project (in this case, the parent `entera-demo-design` and two children `entera-demo-design-1-01` and `entera-demo-design-1-00`).

Note that the command `mvn compile package install` is redundant, as [Maven lifecycle phases](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html) are run in order, so `install` will *always* run `compile` and `package` (as well as other phases) first.

If needed, it is possible to build a single subproject with the `--projects <submodule>` or `-pl <submodule>` command-line option, as in:

```
mvn install --projects entera-demo-design-1-01
```

This is usually not necessary or desirable, however. It is typical to build multi-module projects as a group.

Comment: Thanks, I did  as you suggested, and it worked.